# Jquery get element value and then set it into chart js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

here is my input field that can add with users (it is repetitive fields), and my chart that created with chart.js

I want to show user input value in chart.
user fill the input element.

I want to replace dynamically user input value with chart column after click on a simple button.

here is my code:

```js
anychart.onDocumentLoad(function() {
  var chart = anychart.column([
    ["Winter", 2],
    ["Spring", 7],
    ["Summer", 6],
    ["Fall", 10]
  ]);
  // set chart title
  chart.title("chart title");
  // set chart container and draw
  chart.container("container").draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/latest/anychart-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<table class="acf-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="example">
                <input type="text" value="99">
            </td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td class="example">
                <input type="text" value="67">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="example">
                <input type="text" value="45">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="example">
                <input type="text" value="87">
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: write onclick handler and then get value of inputs using `$("#inputid").val()` then pass same inside your chart .

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to

- use `anychart.data.set()`
- convert array to object key value using `dataSet.mapAs()`
- add `input` event to the input element
- and to update `.set(index, [object key name], newValue)`

```js
anychart.onDocumentLoad(function() {
  var dataSet = anychart.data.set([
    ["Winter", 2],
    ["Spring", 7],
    ["Summer", 6],
    ["Fall", 10]
  ]);
  var chart = anychart.column();
  // set chart title
  chart.title("chart title");
  // set data
  var column = chart.column(dataSet);
  var view = dataSet.mapAs({
    key: 0,
    value: 1
  });

  // set chart container and draw
  chart.container("container").draw();

  // update on input
  $('.example input').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).on('input', function() {
      console.log(view.get(index, 'key'), item.value)
      view.set(index, 'value', item.value)
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/latest/anychart-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/latest/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<table class="acf-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="7">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="6">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="example">
        <input type="text" value="10">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: thank you. An unresolved issue the chart data set count default is 4.
but i want to set this count by the number of "input field" that can 1 filed or 50 field. when my number of input field is 5, i want that the chart show the 5 value.

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: yes that possible, but that different question to solve, it better to create new question.